# Working way on creating a root ftp user

Tags: ftp, debian

There are many work arounds for this. One of those I've done:

```
adduser username
chown -R username /directory/
chmod -R 755 /directory/
```

I'm using FlashFXP on Windows which ends to

```
[R] USER xxx
[R] 331 Password required for xxx
[R] PASS (hidden)
[R] 530 Login incorrect.
[R] Connection failed
```

But I wanna make a ftp user on root **~** directory.

***Also tried:***

Adding `/bin/false` to `/etc/shells`

```
nano /etc/shells
useradd userftp -p mypass -d /home -s /bin/false
passwd userftp
/etc/init.d/proftpd start
```

Can't login either!

**proftpd.conf**

```
ServerName              "Myserver"
ServerType              standalone

Port                    21
PassivePorts            35000 35999
UseReverseDNS           off
TimesGMT                off
TimeoutLogin            120
TimeoutIdle             600
TimeoutNoTransfer       900
TimeoutStalled          3600

ScoreboardFile                  /var/run/proftpd/proftpd.pid

TransferLog             /var/log/proftpd/xferlog.legacy
LogFormat               default "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b"
LogFormat               auth    "%v [%P] %h %t \"%r\" %s"
LogFormat               write   "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b"

#DON'T modify this log format.  It's used by DirectAdmin to determine user usage
LogFormat               userlog "%u %b %m %a"
ExtendedLog             /var/log/proftpd/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.bytes WRITE,READ userlog

AuthUserFile                    /etc/proftpd.passwd
DefaultServer           on
AuthOrder mod_auth_file.c

#AuthPAM off

<IfModule mod_tls.c>
        TLSEngine on
        TLSLog /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.tls.log
        TLSProtocol SSLv23
        #TLSProtocol TLSv1
        TLSVerifyClient off
        TLSRequired off

        #Certificates
        TLSRSACertificateFile /etc/exim.cert
        TLSRSACertificateKeyFile /etc/exim.key
        #TLSCACertificateFile /etc/ftpd/root.cert.pem

        TLSCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:+TLSv1:!SSLv2:+SSLv3
</IfModule>

<Global>
        PassivePorts            35000 35999
        DeferWelcome            on

        RequireValidShell       no

        DefaultRoot             ~
        DirFakeUser on ftp
        DirFakeGroup on ftp

        User                    ftp
        Group                   ftp
        #UserAlias              anonymous ftp

        AllowStoreRestart       on
        AllowRetrieveRestart    on

        ListOptions             -a
        ShowSymlinks            on
        <IfModule mod_facts.c>
                ##Enable this with proftpd 1.3.4b+ to fix FileZilla MLSD
                ##http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_facts.html#FactsOptions
                # FactsOptions UseSlink
        </IfModule>

        Umask                   022
        DisplayLogin            welcome.msg
        DisplayChdir            readme
        AllowOverwrite          yes
        IdentLookups            off
        ExtendedLog             /var/log/proftpd/access.log WRITE,READ write
        ExtendedLog             /var/log/proftpd/auth.log AUTH auth

        #
        # Paranoia logging level....
        #
        #ExtendedLog    /var/log/proftpd/paranoid.log ALL default

        <IfModule mod_tls.c>
                TLSEngine on
                TLSLog /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.tls.log
                TLSRSACertificateFile /etc/exim.cert
                TLSRSACertificateKeyFile /etc/exim.key
        </IfModule>
</Global>

Include /etc/proftpd.vhosts.conf
```

Comment: please try to always explain your goal, what you have tried, and more over please try to be precise in your explanation.

Comment: @Kiwy It's obvious that I'm trying to add a user with above commands, I _think_ user is created but I can't connect to that ftp user.

Comment: obviously it's not because we don't know if you set up correctly this user, we don't know if your daemon is configured correctly and we don't know the daemon you're using

Comment: @Kiwy I'm new to linux so what I've tried is just installing proftpd via apt-get command and then trying to add user, as many topics that only warpped these things. If there should be something more I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: please **[edit]** your question to add any relevant piece of information to you question, like your `proftpd` configuration

Comment: @Kiwy updated..

Comment: Question does not make sense.  Are you trying to create a new user, or log in as root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your configuration, you should change

```
AuthOrder mod_auth_file.c
```

by

```
 AuthOrder mod_auth_pam.c* mod_auth_unix.c
```

Because `mod_auth_file.c` is made only for use the proftpd special auth file.
You can consult AuthOrder options here ==> [Proftpd AuthOrder directive](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_AuthOrder.html)

Comment: I see that default conf file has `AuthOrder mod_auth_pam.c* mod_auth_unix.c` which is commented but in mine was `AuthOrder mod_auth_file.c` Is it supposed to be changed without user modify it?

Comment: What do you mean?  Config files are usually only modifiable by root or a priviledge account. It really depends what you want to do. Setting user in a file or use system login .